# How many five digit numbers formed from digits $1,2,3,4,5$ (used exactly once) are divisible by $12$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, divisibility

> How many five digit numbers formed from digits $1,2,3,4,5$ (used exactly once) are divisible by $12$?

My answer is $24$ but I doubt if it's right or not.

Sum of all the digits is $15$, so all the numbers are divisible by $3$. Also there are $24$ numbers divisible by $4$. I have found this by

- Fixing $4$ at units place , so I must place $2$ at tens place and number divisible by $4$ is $3!=6$
- Fixing $2$ at units place, so I have $1,3$ or $5$ at tens place and number divisible by $4$ is $3!×3=18$

Since $12=3×4$ and all numbers are divisible by $3$ so numbers divisible by $12$ is $24$.

Is the reason valid?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: All the numbers formed from the five digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ are divisible by $3$ since their digit sum is $15$, so you just have to check if the numbers are also divisible by $4$.

Comment: @BJKShah If a number is divisible by $3$ and $4$ , and you divide it by $3$, it's still divisible by $4$ ...

Comment: I understand it now cause the numbers will have both the factors 3 and 4 and so 12 would also divide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decomposition of the problem is valid, and only works because those two divisors are *co-prime* (there is no number bigger than $1$ dividing both divisors). This means that if a number is divisible by $3$ and $4$ it is automatically divisible by $12$, and you can check each condition independently – which you did.

Comment: Like if the factors were 6 and 3 then it is not necessary that 18 would divide the numbers, but 12 would?

Comment: @BJKShah Indeed.